# How to make sure that a binary installed in a conda env has precedence over a binary installed locally?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have two instances of a software installed in my computer, whenever I enter the command for running this software, it uses the binary installed on my system, not the ones installed via Conda, how can I have the right command on my path?

Answer (score 0):

Anything you have installed in a conda environment using conda will take precedence over anything else. Make sure you run your command within an active environment (`conda activate <your_environment>` before you run your command).